# What are the differences between normal functions and Marionette.Commands

Tags: javascript, function, marionette

After reading `Marionette.Commands` I am very curious to finding difference between normal functions and `Marionette.Commands`.

If you define any function, you can call that function wherever you want.

normal Function :

```
var normalFun=function(){alert("Normal Function")};
```

same way `Marionette.commands` also working like in the following way.

```
//creating instance for Application class
var myApp=new Marionette.Application();
//registering command
myApp.Commands.setHandler("functionName",function(){alert("This is just a normal function but way of defining as different in my point of view.")});
//whereever you want to call this command just run that command with corresponding name
myApp.Commands.execute("functionName");
```

What I am thinking, both normal functions and `Marionette.Commands` are same. If it is right then why did `Marionette` developers develop this `Marionette.Commands` concept?

Answer (score 4):

To use a function, you need to either call it from the same scope, or have a reference to a containing object. This isn't the case for commands, so they allow for decoupling.

Say you want to change the color of the menu when a user clicks on some button in your app. You can define a `changeColor` function in (e.g.) the portion of your application that manages the header. Then, you can make the menu color change by calling (e.g.) `myHeader.changeColor()` from somewhere in your application. But as mentioned above, that means you need a reference to `myHeader` to be able to call its `changeColor` method.

As you develop your application, you realize that actually the menu itself is getting quite complex, and it makes more sense for it to change its own color directly (instead of having the header manage the color). Now you need to go in your application and change every instance of `myHeader.changeColor()` to `myMenu.changeColor()`. This is due to the coupling of the various bits of your application.

If instead you use commands, you would execute the command from the places that need to change the menu color, and you'd define the handler in the "header" part. Then when you decide to change your application design, you can simply move the handler so it's defined in the "menu" part. With this solution, you won't have to change the actual calls to change the menu color, because they're entirely decoupled.

With both solutions, you can change the menu color. But using commands allows for better decoupling and less work down the road. Of course, this doesn't mean you should use commands everywhere: adapt their use (or not) to your particular case.

Comment: Literally _just_ finished your book. Awesome.

Comment: Thanks! I just started working on a new book with more advanced content. Stay tuned! (Also, would you mind adding your feedback at https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction/feedback ? I'd appreciate it.)

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. I mean everything is the same down the road (a function), always. Haha.

What's important is what you make out of it. So, in the end, it is just a matter of taste/professionalism (respecting patterns, conventions, etc..).

With the `commands`, you have everything in one place and only `myApp` is responsible for communicating between the modules/the controllers/the domains/whatever *"functional end result"* (to quote [@David Sulc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492513/david-sulc) very good book: "[Backbone.Marionette.js: A Gentle Introduction](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction)") of your application.

So long story short: In a big app, it makes sense to only pass around the `myApp` instance, and executes the commands from there.

*Note*: And that makes even more sense when you're using RequireJS.

That's cleaner, more structured.